# Django: Sort query with common column value

Tags: django, sorting

Hey, Let's say I have this model:

```
class Log:
 msg = CharField(...)
 project = ForeignKey(..)
 date = DateField(..)
```

Now let's say I want to select the 4 most recent logs:

```
 logs = Log.objects.order_by('project').order_by('-date')[:4]
```

Further, I want to extract the logs that share the same project so in my template, I'd like to do something like:

```
 {% for proj in projects %}
   [Do something with the proj model instance]
   {% for log in proj.logs(?) %}
     [Do something with logs]
   {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

How to?

Comment: How do the two parts of your question link together?

Comment: You want to select some projects and then iterate over the logs in those projects? As long as there is a foreign key that is all you need to do... for log in proj.log_set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template you could [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) by project.

From the docs something (untested) like

```
{% regroup logs|dictsort:"project.id" by project as project_list %}

{% for project in project_list %}
    {{ project.grouper }}
        {% for item in project.list %}
            [Do something with logs]
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for proj in projects %}
  {{ proj.name }}
  {% for log in proj.log_set.all %}
    {{ log.msg }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you use a `related_name` for your ForeignKey (let's say "logs") you could you could use
proj.logs instead of proj.log_set. Check the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

If you need the latest logs for a project on a regular basis i'd consider writing a method for your Project model:

```
def recent_logs(self):
    return self.log_set.all()[:4]
```

Then you could adjust the loop in your template to:

```
{% for log in proj.recent_logs %}
    {{ log.msg }}
{% endfor %}
```